# ARIMA model throws "LinAlgError("SVD did not converge")" error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statsmodels, forecasting

My ultimate goal is to predict what a given server's  **Use%** of disk 
(as in the Use% from df -h:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3              39G   31G  6.9G  82% /
```

)

will be at future date using machine learning.I'm leveraging the ARIMA model from the statsmodels python library to do time-series forecasting.

I have an array containing daily tuples I recorded over many days,  of format (epoch_timestamp, used_pct):

```
results = [(1545346993, 80), (1545433403, 79), (1545519793, 80), (1545606202, 82), (1545692596, 80), (1545779002, 83), (1545865397, 77), (1545951799, 76), (1546038202, 75), (1546124601, 73), (1546210994, 73), (1546297394, 73), (1546383797, 73), (1546470197, 74), (1546556595, 74)]
```

If you see the minimum code example below, it errs with

> "LinAlgError: SVD did not converge".

Interestingly, if you  modify this specific tuple   - results[6]
 from:

```
(1545865397, 77)
```

to:

```
(1545865397, 80)
```

The code then works as expected , with this output:

```
predicted=77.635415, expected=73.000000
predicted=69.932872, expected=73.000000
predicted=76.074475, expected=73.000000
predicted=73.698213, expected=73.000000
predicted=72.721116, expected=74.000000
predicted=73.054932, expected=74.000000
Test MSE: 7.227
```

So that tells me something data-specific is causing this. From researching other questions, I ensured there is no np.Nan values or other bad data. At any rate, here is the full example using the 'bad' tuple:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA


time_list = []
used_pct_list = []
results = [(1545346993, 80), (1545433403, 79), (1545519793, 80), (1545606202, 82), (1545692596, 80), (1545779002, 83), (1545865397, 77), (1545951799, 76), (1546038202, 75), (1546124601, 73), (1546210994, 73), (1546297394, 73), (1546383797, 73), (1546470197, 74), (1546556595, 74)]
for time, used_pct in results:
    time_list.append(time)
    used_pct_list.append(used_pct)

data = np.array(used_pct_list)
series = pd.Series(data,index=time_list)
X = series.values

size = int(len(X) * 0.66)
train, test = X[0:size], X[size:len(X)]
history = [x for x in train]

predictions = list()
for t in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(5,1,0))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
    output = model_fit.forecast()
    yhat = output[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    obs = test[t]
    history.append(obs)
    print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat, obs))
error = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
print('Test MSE: %.3f' % error)
```

and the error it throws:

```
runfile('C:/Users/user/.spyder-py3/blarg_bad.py', wdir='C:/Users/user/.spyder-py3')
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\signaltools.py:1341: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  out_full[ind] += zi
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\signaltools.py:1344: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  out = out_full[ind]
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\signaltools.py:1350: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  zf = out_full[ind]
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\tsatools.py:607: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
....
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 1562, in svd
    u, s, vh = gufunc(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 98, in _raise_linalgerror_svd_nonconvergence
    raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge")

LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
```

I am new to machine learning and  have been using this site as a guide on arima models: https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/